# windows form control property?

Tags: vb.net, controls

Good day everyone,

I just want to ask how to do this on vb.net using vs2010 
It's like a label(i'm not sure if it's really a label), like this

[image]

and when you put the cursor on it, it will show a "button"?.. like this,
[image]

Comment: its ToolTip control, just go through this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/885/How-To-Add-ToolTips-To-Controls-On-A-Windows-Form)

Comment: it is not a big thing just add too tip to the control http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: maybe what you're looking for is a toolstrip control to create a toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Control to create the menu is called a [toolstrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolstrip(v=vs.110).aspx):
Tutorial for this:

[Tooltrips - basics](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets13p2.html)
[.Net Heaven](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/toolstrip-control-in-vb.net)

To add those labels when hovering above it, you must use a [tooltip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.settooltip(v=vs.110).aspx).

There is a built in option (that doesn't require an extra control)

Tutorial: [MSDN- How to: Use ToolTips in ToolStrip Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171703(v=vs.100).aspx)

But you could implement the behavior yourself using the control "tooltip".
Here's some tutorials on how to implement it:

[Tooltips](http://www.help-info.de/en/Visual_Basic_net/vbnet_tooltip.htm)

[.Net Heaven](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/article/tooltip-control-in-vb.net)

[Dotnetperls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tooltip)

Enjoy

Comment: Please do not provide complete link-only answers. Show the important steps as code examples. Links can be broken when the respective websites shut down and your answer thus be rendered quite useless for future readers.

Comment: Good point - code should indeed be always supplied instead of links. Although i didn't want to provide code/tutorial in the response because one such tutorial would take up way too much space (probably even too much space for one single answer) and it would literally be copy-paste (And i don't want to enjoy credit for someone else his tutorial/work).

Comment: With as much effort as there is in the question, I think the answer is good enough to NOT be downvoted. It contains some useful and relevant information in regard to OP's issue. A full answer would be too broad, consider the question is "do this for me" style. +1